# if else statement with a function

Tags: javascript, if-statement

So I'm totally new to this and I've got an assignment which I can't figure out. The assignment is:
1. Write a function stopLight with a parameter color.
2. By calling the action with a color (eg. red) it needs to show a string by using return.
3. Make sure that when you use red the 'stop' string returns
4. if green then "go"
5. Put a console.log in with a parameter/argument the function calls with the color of the traffic light. This has to be visible in the console.

What I have till now is this:

```
function stopLight(color){
return color;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=stopLight("red");
if (stopLight("red")){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Stop";
}
else if (stopLight("green")) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Go";
}
```

Like I said I'm just starting with JavaScript so please be gentle :)

Comment: please consider reading the documentation prior to posting questions.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the requirements. While your function just returns what it's given, the requirements state it should return, for instance, `"stop"` when you give it `"red"`

Comment: `Stoplight` is useless right now. It just return one color. The if isn't checking nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function stopLight(color){
    color = color.toLowerCase();
    if ( color === "red") {
        console.log(color);
        return 'Stop';
    } else if (color === 'green') {
        console.log(color);
        return 'Go'
    }
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=stopLight("red");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function stopLight(color){
       if(color==="red")
            return "stop";
       return "go"
}
console.log(stopLight("red"))
console.log(stopLight("green"))
```